# Get an error after I log in to Magento

Tags: php, magento, admin, magento-1.9

I had recently installed the [Layered Navigation SEO](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html) extension for my Magento web shop.

Sadly after I try to log in I get the following error:

```
Indexeermodel moet Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract uitbreiden.
#0 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/Mage_Index_Model_Process.php(315): Mage::throwException('Indexeermodel m...')
#1 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications.php(41): Mage_Index_Model_Process->getIndexer()
#2 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/index/notifications.phtml(27): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->getProcessesForReindex()
#3 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(3387): include('/home/frozen1q/...')
#4 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(3418): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#5 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(3432): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications.php(67): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(2592): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()
#9 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(13594): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(2592): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#11 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(2310): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(2254): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
#13 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
#14 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(3387): include('/home/frozen1q/...')
#15 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(3418): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(3432): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(2592): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(28076): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(13987): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#21 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#22 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(14015): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#23 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(18399): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#24 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(17933): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/includes/src/__default.php(20705): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/frozen1q/public_html/cuijkwheels.nl/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

I really tried everything to try to solve this problem, like manually deactivating the extension, deleting the extension files, trying to make modifications to the Varian.php file, but unfortunately without an result.

What am I supposed to do? I use Magento 1.9.

Comment: Did you flush your cache and logout/flush browser cache?

Comment: Yes ofcourse this is the standard action I do after each change on Magento.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have Magento `Compilation` enabled. Try after disabling it from backend.

Comment: I disabled the Comilation as you said, but now I get a blank page of the admin panel.

Comment: Have you deleted `var` folder ?

Comment: No, am I supposed to delete this folder?